# How do you move a folder into another folder

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-foundation, folder

In a documents folder, how do you move one folder (ex. human resources folder into a corporate office folder)

Answer (score 5):

Use windows explorer, in 2010/2013 it's found on the library tab of the library (and only works in IE on windows)

Comment: Will the documents in the folder you are moving get checked out or will they remain checked in?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the `Library` view from the top window bar `Library Tools`.
2. Select `Datasheet View` within the `View Format` section of the Ribbon Bar.
3. Select `Open with Explorer` within the `Connect and Export` section of the Ribbon Bar.
4. An MS Explorer window will open.
5. Move files/folders in the same way as with the file system Explorer.

Comment: Works perfectly!